# ultrasonic setup guide

Tags: ultrasound, setup

Does anybody know of any online resources that go over the setup of driving ultrasonic transducers, as well as how to receive an ultrasonic echo, and pick it out (for rangefinding)?

I found [this](http://www.ee.latrobe.edu.au/~djc/UltraSonics/Ultrasonics.htm) article online...but it glosses over it almost too much.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the ultrasound? What are you coupling the signal into? (air? water? steel?). These things do matter when deciding what to do with the signal.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered an ultrasonic "module" like one of these? http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=8502

It will take care of most of the details for you.

Answer (score 1):

Texas [TL852](http://focus.ti.com/docs/prod/folders/print/tl852.html) and [TL851](http://focus.ti.com/docs/prod/folders/print/tl851.html) are two devices that you can use to make an ultrasonic range finder.  See their website for datasheets

Answer (score 1):

Some information on ultrasonic hardware can be found [here](http://david.carybros.com/html/ultrasonic.html).